# How to make image behind invisible button look like it was pressed down?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uibutton, ibaction

Hi I have a couple of images that are covered by an invisible button. Is there a way that I can make it look like the images were pressed down when I press the invisible button? Thanks!

Comment: can you post your HTML? Depending on the structure of the HTML you might be able to use CSS for this, but surely you can use Js to do a simple image swape based on relative nodes.

Comment: If you have a reference to the imageviews. You can just set the highlighted image for the imageview and then call setHighlited on the user press event.

Comment: As @db2burke said CSS is needed for this. The smoothest way to achieve this is with an image sprite. Google Css image sprites which are basically one image containing different images for however many states you require.

Comment: @Bergasms I'm doing what you said but the image doesn't look any different. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: Hmm not sure. Assuming the reference to the UIImageVIew is hooked up correctly it should work ok. You can always just change the image in the UIImageView instead of using the highlighted state, So on button push just do [imgview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"highlightimage"]] and on release [imgview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"normalImage"]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the image directly onto the button, you dont need a seperate `UIImageView`.

```
[button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

The are a few more `UIControlState` constants.

Take a look at the docs:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIControlState

Comment: I definitely would do this, however its a little more complicated of a situation. there are three separate images that the invisible button is covering and one of them is an animation array that starts frequently, and another is an image that switches between two images. Thanks though